# how to disallow modifying data when the spinner continuing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a screen, when I click on submit button, I will start one spinner to disallow performing any other operations.

But when I enter data in text-field, there is a ng-change function in text field. while entering the data, spinner will starts, even though the cursor is in the text field, so I am able to change the data.

But I want to restrict modifying data when spinner start.

Comment: can you add `ng-disabled="loading"` on your text-field? Then whenever the spinner is initiated you set `loading` to true, disabling the field from any actions

Comment: But i have many text fields in one screen.

Comment: if you want to start spinner on the click of submit button, then instead of starting spinner on any change, you should start on ng-submit, ie when your want your form to be submitted, and after saving the form remove the spinner. And make sure your spinner should cover the whole form so that user is unable to click in any input field.

Comment: No..we  have ng-changes for multiple fields.

Comment: Use a library such as [Block-UI](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui) which will obscure your form by creating another layer on top of the form so that elements can't be interacted with because all clicks go on the top layer.

Comment: keep in mind that the user is in full control over front-end. If you need to block any further modifications, do so in your back-end

Comment: If you have a bunch of text fields and you don't want to add `ng-disabled` to each one, you can wrap all the fields inside a single `<fieldset>` element and then set `ng-disabled` on the `<fieldset>`. It will disable all controls contained within it.